# How to convert Pointer-to-String to lowercase?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, operator-overloading

I am learning Overloaded Operators and trying overload unary `-` operator to convert a string-pointer that contains a string to lowercase letters.
This is my `.h` file :

```
class Mystring {
    
    friend Mystring operator-(Mystring &obj);
    
private :
    string *ptr;
public :
    Mystring();
    Mystring(string s);
    ~Mystring();
    
    void get_info();
};
```

This is my `.cpp` file (Constructors and Destructor have been defined) :

```
#include <algorithm>
Mystring operator-(Mystring &obj) {
    transform(obj.ptr.begin(), obj.ptr.end(), obj.ptr.begin() ::tolower);  //ERROR
    return obj;
}
```

This is my `main.cpp` :

```
int main() {
Mystring B {"THIS SHOULD BE LOWECASE"};
B = -B;
B.getinfo();  //Displays *(B->ptr)
return 0;
}
```

The line commented with "ERROR" throws 1 error with each argument to the function `transform()`. I think there's a syntactical error. HOW TO FIX THIS ?[This is the error message I get with each .begin() and .end() arguement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y28OG.png)

Comment: You write 'obj.ptr.begin()' but 'prt' is a pointer to a string, hence you should write 'obj.ptr->begin()' etc.
[edit]

Comment: There should be also a comma before '::tolower'.

Comment: THANK YOU ! That fixed it. Now that all errors have been fixed, the program runs fine. BUT, after `return obj;` in `operator-()` , the destructor gets called which causes the program to crash. Any idea why ?

Comment: Show us the copy constructor and the destructor. Probably it does not copy the string but only the pointer. When Mystring gets copied when returned form 'operator-', you get two objects pointing the same string. It result in double deletion. This is only my suspicion, so please show us the code.

Comment: I changed the prototype and definition to  `Mystring &operator-(Mystring &obj)` and returned the reference using `return &obj;` and it worked fine without crash. I have not provided a copy constructor and the destructor has `delete ptr;`. Did this solve the double deletion problem or some other problem that I do not know of ?

Comment: Rather not. The copy constructor should allocate a new object and copy the data like this:
'this->ptr = new string(*(obj->ptr))'

BTW. copy constructor should take 'const Mystring &'

Comment: One more thing. Using operators overloading for such operations is not the best idea - someone who will read your code (maybe you yourself in a few weeks) will have problems with understand the logic. It is better to write a properly named method like 'toLowerCase'.

Comment: To your second comment, I undesrtand that, I am just practicing while learning to thats why I didnt name it properly. Sorry for that.
To your earlier comment, I did not understand what you mean. Are you referring to Deep & Shallow Copy ?

Comment: Also, looks like I made a mistake in earlier comment where I changed the prototype to avoid crash.
here's operator- function that doesnt cause crash : 
`Mystring &operator-(Mystring &obj) {
transform(obj.ptr->begin(), obj.ptr->end(), obj.ptr->begin(), ::tolower);
return obj;
}`
I added `&` before `operator-`. Can you please explain what changed and fixed the crash ? Also, sorry for all these questions, I am just eager to learn and you seem to be really helpful. Thank You ! You may choose to ignore this post if you feel like it.

Comment: Yes, I am. You should make a deep copy or count instances in the case of shallow copying. Otherwise, the string will be deleted two or more times. You can use std::shared_ptr for that, instead of bare pointers. But I would avoid that because the behavior of the program would be hard to predict.

Comment: Adding '&' resulted in returning reference instead of copying. I would return a copy and fix the copy constructor.

Comment: allright, Ill fix my code. Thank You Very much !